# <img> <a href.....> there is a lot of space between img and a

Tags: html, image

I have below code. But does not know why there is so many space shown in web page between `<img>` and `<a href .....>`

```
<div class="main-container">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-9 page-content col-thin-right">
<div class="inner-box category-content">
<h2 class="title-2">Find Under the following Listing</h2>
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
<div class="cat-list">
<h3 class="cat-title">
<img src=images/category_icon/Dress.png alt='' height='30' width='30'>
<a href='http://example.com/index.php/getCategory/getAll/1/1'>Dress (5)</a>
<span data-target=".cat-id-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn-cat-collapsed collapsed"> <span class=" icon-down-open-big"></span> </span></h3>

<ul class="cat-collapse collapse in cat-id-1">
<li> .............
```

Comment: can you fiddle this ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to both `<img>` and `<a href=....>` :

```
style="margin:0px; padding :0px"
```